# in TFS2013 How is Code Coverage total calculated

Tags: code-coverage

I have the following %line Covered show up in the Code Coverage Result in TFS 2013.

```
30.87%
19.28%
90.38%
6.77%
22.15%
0.54%
81.55%
4.28%
```

The Total shows up as 15.85% in VS 2013, what formula is used to derive that number.
If i calculate an average it is 31.98, not sure how 15.85 is derived from above metrics ?

Any insight ?

Comment: It's most likely a *weighted* average.  There might only be three lines of code in the 90.38 percent figure, but 200 lines of code in the 4.18 percent figure.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio (Premium and up) and TFS use code blocks as it's measure for coverage, this made up of lines and paths through the code.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667391(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

As stated in the comments you may have 100% on 2 blocks and 5% on 100